# MySQL: Is it possible to have an IF subquery?

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to run a subquery inside of an if statement used in the SELECT, but I'm getting an error. I've never needed to do something similar before so I've never tried this until now. Here is what I'm running:

```
SELECT t1.*, IF(t1.tin > 0, (SELECT name FROM special_packaging WHERE id = t1.tin), 0), t2.productname, t2.imagepath FROM cartitems AS t1 INNER JOIN products AS t2 ON t1.productid = t2.id WHERE t1.cartid = 8
```

I'm getting a syntax error. Is it possible to run a subquery inside of an IF statement?

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the error message I am getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: It *should* work (even if it isn't necessarily the most optimum approach)... please post the actual error you get in response to that query.

Comment: I added the error in my question above.

Comment: Curious. You might try that query again; I see no syntax error in it. The `...the right syntax to use near '' at line...` error message means the parser found whatever is shown in the quotes, at a place where that thing doesn't belong; empty string `''` means the parser got to the end of the query while still in the middle of something and expecting more; example: `SELECT * FROM;` will generate the same error, because it expects something, anything, other than an empty string, after the `FROM`.  (The semicolon would have already been removed).

Comment: I checked it again this morning and got the same result and I too am stumped. I've re-read the query and re-typed it thinking maybe I just typed it too quickly and overlooked a typo, but this exact query gives me the same error each time. Perhaps I should remove the * and try doing things the quicker and probably more accurate way. My boss has me in a hurry so I attempted to take the lazy route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably convert it to a more-standard `JOIN` and a `CASE` statement, personally:

```
SELECT
     t1.*
    ,CASE WHEN t1.tin > 0 THEN sp.name ELSE 0 END
    ,t2.productname
    ,t2.imagepath
FROM cartitems AS t1
JOIN products AS t2
  ON t1.productid = t2.id
LEFT JOIN special_packaging sp
       ON sp.id = t1.tin
WHERE t1.cartid = 8
```

Comment: I just did this and it worked greatly. I really appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `CASE WHEN t1.tin > 0 THEN logic1 ELSE logic2 END AS fieldname` like below in your query and I also give another reference of my query.

> Implementation in your query

```
SELECT t1.*,CASE WHEN t1.tin > 0 THEN (SELECT name FROM special_packaging WHERE id = t1.tin) ELSE (SELECT another_name FROM another_table WHERE id = t1.tin) END AS final_name,
t2.productname, t2.imagepath FROM cartitems AS t1 INNER JOIN products AS t2 ON t1.productid = t2.id WHERE t1.cartid = 8
```

> My Query

```
$videos = mysqli_query($con, "select a.*,
(select country_name from country_names 
        where country_id='" . $country_id . "' ) AS country_name,
        (select country_lang_name from country_languages  where 
        country_lang_id='" . $country_lang_id . "' ) AS country_lang_name,
        CASE WHEN a.is_Particle > 0 THEN 
        (select prefab_name from particle where 
        id=a.GameobjectName) ELSE (select prefab_name from particle_offline where 
        id=a.GameobjectName) END AS prefab_name
         from videos a where " . $record['Cat_tag'] . "=1 
         and FIND_IN_SET('" . $country_id . "',a.country_id)>0
         and FIND_IN_SET('" . $country_lang_id . "',a.country_lang_id)>0");
```